# Trying to get rid of some letters in string

Tags: javascript

```
let myDate = new Date();
myDate.toLocaleString;
```

So if I'll console log the value of `myDate` will be:

```
Wed Oct 16 2019 15:57:22 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time)
```

What if I want the value to be only 57:22? (Minutes and seconds of the hour).
How do I do that?

Comment: `myDate.getMinutes()`, `myDate.getSeconds()` or use something to format it specifically.

Comment: You can use a date library such as `moment` or `date-fns` to parse a date and format it in any way you'd like. For example, in moment you could do `moment(new Date()).format('MM:ss')`

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with this

```js
const getMMSS = (str) => str.match(/:\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0].slice(1); 

// tests
const myDate = new Date(2019,09,16,23,59,59,999);
let dateStr =  myDate.toLocaleString();
console.log(getMMSS(dateStr))
dateStr =  "Wed Oct 16 2019 15:57:22 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time)"
console.log(getMMSS(dateStr))
```

Or just

```js
const pad = (num) => ("0"+num).slice(-2);
const myDate = new Date();
console.log(`${pad(myDate.getMinutes())}:${pad(myDate.getSeconds())}`)
```

Comment: Please explain slice(2) vs slice(3)

Comment: AM/PM vs 24 hours. I fixed it

Comment: No, that will match HH:MM first

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date`'s own methods to do this:

```
let date = new Date();

let m = date.getMinutes();
let s = date.getSeconds();

console.log(m + ':' + s);
```

To make the final result more readable you can check if the minutes and seconds are smaller than 10 and, if so, append a 0 to the beginning:

```
let date = new Date();

let m = date.getMinutes();
let s = date.getSeconds();

m = m < 10 ? ('0' + m) : m;
s = s < 10 ? ('0' + s) : s;

console.log(m + ':' + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use basic javascript Date methods:

```js
var myDate = new Date();
var formatted =`${myDate.getMinutes()}:${myDate.getSeconds()}`;
console.log(formatted);
```

OR using moment.js library

```js
var myDate = new Date();
var formatted = moment(myDate).format("mm:ss");
console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Will give you 9:9 for 09:09

Comment: Moment libary is better. Thank you for teaching me that. I'm still trying to put it inside a chart and doesn't get it...